# Upload a big dta stata file with pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, stata

I have a *stata_file.dta* of 3 gb and I want to load that file using pyspark because with *pandas* it takes a long time to load.

Comment: what is the `dta` file?

Comment: Stata software files use the extension dta

Comment: Export the .dta to csv in Stata. The meta information useful in Stata in the .dta format lost when exporting to .csv will be lost anyway when importing to a Spark dataframe.

Comment: @AlexAmaguaya Have you tried with `chunksize` param in pandas ?
Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_stata.html#pandas-read-stata